# Netbeans doesn't recognize AMPPS project folder Mac OS 10.8

Tags: wordpress, macos, netbeans, virtual-machine

I am using AMPPS to host a wordpress site I'm working on.  Mac OS 10.8.  I just installed Netbeans IDE 8.0 but when creating a new project, could not select my site folder > AMPPS > Applications.

I made an alias of the site folder and put it on my desktop.  Netbeans doesn't recognize it.  It actually does not recognize anything inside the Applications folder, but does in others like my documents folder.

Any help much appreciated.